# How to get the eclipse platform version in "2022-03" programmatically

Tags: java, eclipse

I need to get the Eclipse version in `2022-03` format programmatically.

I am trying using `Platform.getBundle("org.eclipse.platform").getVersion()`

but it is giving the version in `4.23.0.v20220308-0310` format.

Could anyone have a suggestion, please?

Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2022-03 is the name of the whole product package, rather than Eclipse Platform which is just one component. 4.23 is the correct version for Platform.

As far as I am aware the 2022-03 name is only present in the `about.mappings` file in the "defining bundle" for the product and is just used in the "about" text.

The about.mappings looks something like

```
# about.mappings
# contains fill-ins for about.properties
# java.io.Properties file (ISO 8859-1 with "\" escapes)
# This file does not need to be translated.

0=I20220817-1800
1=2022-09
2=4.25
```

You can read this using:

```java
IProduct product = Platform.getProduct();

Bundle bundle = product.getDefiningBundle();

URL location = FileLocator.find(bundle, new Path("about.mappings"));

try (InputStream is = location.openStream())
 {
   ResourceBundle res = new PropertyResourceBundle(is);

   String version = res.getString("1");
 }
catch (final IOException ex)
 {
   ...
 }
```

This is based on code in `org.eclipse.ui.internal.ProductProperties`